# TableHeading Lines Do Not Show Up

Tags: output-formatting, version-9

For a list `list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e"}};` Table heading lines do not show up

```
TableForm[list, TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But it works if the list `list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}};`

```
TableForm[list, TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

[image]

It seems the lines appear only for rectangular list. Is this a bug or i am missing something? I use v9.0.1 Thank you.

Comment: I think Mathematica calls these "ragged tables", and doesn't draw the lines: "Arrays in which all sublists at a particular level are not of the same length display as ragged tables."

Comment: As a workaround you can pad with "" `list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e"}};
TableForm[PadRight[list, Automatic, ""], TableHeadings -> Automatic]`

Comment: @ssch please consider posting this as an answer :)